# Unable to run newly added application in windows server

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am new to windows server and using IIS 7. I have added a new application "**admin01**" in the already running website (say **www.mywebsite.com**) hosted on IIS. When I go to that specific path, say **www.mywebsite.com/admin01**, instead of the application running I see the directory listing of that application. Can anybody tell me if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem in the web.config of the newly added application as its connection string was conflicting with that of the main website. I just encapsulated the connection string of the main website in the  tag and —voila!— it worked perfectly.